# How to lie two canvas at one Tab Navigator?

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, tabnavigator

I want to lie two canvas at one Tab Navigator. when I use

```
<mx:local
```

it created multiple tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them into container (VBox/HBox/whatever), it becomes a new tab. Then lay canvas in the container as you like.